# Using database offline, then updating when new connection established with iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I have been requested to make my app available off-line, which means storing the data collected via Api for use when no connection available. The problem is that when a new connection is made my local data may be out of date. Also, any changes made while off-line will need to update the server.

I'm aware of a method of syncing databases so that when new connection is made the data is automatically updated both ways. However, after browsing Google I've not found a definitive method of doing this.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a field like a time stamp to indicate last synced time. When ever connection is online go for a fetch validate against the timestamp and update the data in offline storage.

The same way, when you have updates while offline you can set some bool value to check whether data is synced or not and sync when you are online.